# Installing Oracle SQL Developer in Arch

Tags: arch-linux, oracle-linux, sql

I've spent >3 hrs trying to figure this out.

I've done [both methods shown in the wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Oracle_client). Both seem to have worked fine. When I search I can't find any newly installed software with any name like "oracle", "instant", "sql." I can't find anything with `which.` So where the **** did it install to? How do I run it?

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed it correctly, ie., so the software is tracked by pacman, then you can print a list of the binaries available with:

```
pacman -Ql $package | awk '/\/usr\/bin/'
```

In some case, the executables may be stored somewhere else, eg., `/opt`, in which case you can read the PKGBUILD for any package in the official repositories or the AUR and look at the `package()` array to determine where the application is installed to on your filesystem. For example,

```
package() {
    cd "$srcdir/instantclient_18_3/"
    install -d "$pkgdir/usr/bin"
    install -d "$pkgdir/usr/lib"
    install -m 755 -t "$pkgdir/usr/bin" adrci genezi uidrvci
```

It is good practice to carefully read any PKGBUILD from the AUR *before* installion not just to determine what it is installing, but to ensure that it is doing so correctly and not in a way that compromises your system, either through incompetence or malfeasance.